# Inputting values in Dash table when testing with Selenium

Tags: selenium, pytest, plotly-dash

I have created a self contained example to explain my problem.

You will find below

- a simple Dash app with one single table.
- an attempt to input a new value in the editable table via Selenium (needed for testing).

Unfortunately nothing happens.

This is not a matter of waiting.

I would really appreciate if you can help me with this one.

Thank you

**app**

```py
import pandas as pd
import dash

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1, 2]
df['b'] = [3, 4]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

server = app.server

app.layout = dash.dash_table.DataTable(
    id="table",
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    editable=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**test**

```py
from dash.testing.application_runners import import_app
import time


def test_change_value(dash_duo):

    app = import_app(app_file='app')

    dash_duo.start_server(app)

    time.sleep(5)

    xpath = '//*[@id="table"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div'
    cell = dash_duo.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    cell.send_keys('test')

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I have tried to access the cell via xpath and send keys as I would for a normal input but it does not seem to work. - Update the question with relevant HTML. Also put some delay before interacting with web element.

Comment: @cruisepandey
Thank you for your feedback. You will find a self contained example above after my edit. Could you please let me know what you think? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to click / clear and change the path before sending the keys. The code below works.

```py
def test_change_value(dash_duo):

    app = import_app(app_file='app')

    dash_duo.start_server(app)

    time.sleep(1)

    xpath = '//*[@id="table"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div'
    cell = dash_duo.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    cell.click()

    xpath = '//*[@id="table"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div/input'
    cell = dash_duo.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    cell.clear()
    cell.send_keys('1234')

    time.sleep(1)
```